# How to translate arabic rows of text from columns into english

Tags: python, pandas, translation

I have a jupyter dataframe with 10,000 rows in arabic that I want to translate to english in an adjacent column. There are actually 2 columns that I want to translate they would be "description" and "text". and next to each of those columns I want new columns with the translation that are called "Description_Translated" and "Text_Translated". Keep in mind that I want to do this using textblob preferably if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a preferred library for translation? A small example table would also be helpful in troubleshooting.

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['Description_Translated'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x))
df['Text_Translated'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x))
```

Ah I just noticed you'd prefer to use textblob. I personally don't know that library but the same idea would work - you can apply a function to the entire column to create a new column.

Comment: do you not have to say what language to and from you are translating too?

Comment: It tries to detect the source language and translate into system default automatically. You can specify if you need to. https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/